# How to translate a console app (C# .Net 7) with System.CommandLine and UseLocalizationResources?

Tags: c#, .net, command-line

I have created a C# .Net 7 console app based on System.CommandLine (preview nuget package 2.0.0-beta4.22272.1). My goal is to localize the app.

- MS Source Code [dotnet/command-line-api](https://github.com/dotnet/command-line-api/)
- Docu MS Source Code [System.Commandline](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/tree/main/docs/standard/commandline)
- Docu [MS Learn - System.CommandLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/commandline/)

I found `UseLocalizationResources` and `LocalizationResources.Instance` but all these classes, have private or internal access modifiers; so no chance to change the behaviour.

In my code I have set, to my target culture info (all with no success)

- CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
- Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
- Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture
- Also I configured the Environment Variable `DOTNET_CLI_UI_LANGUAGE`

The default text will always stays in English, even I set all four above to "de" or "de-DE" (as CultureInfo). The translation of the CLI nuget package I saw here [GitHub - Resource (default)](https://github.com/dotnet/command-line-api/blob/main/src/System.CommandLine/Properties/Resources.resx) and here the [German part](https://github.com/dotnet/command-line-api/blob/main/src/System.CommandLine/Properties/xlf/Resources.de.xlf)

My command call

```
.\tool.exe --l10n de --help
```

```
Description:
  Das CLI tool um XYZ vom Terminal zu nutzen

Usage:
  mytool [options]

Options:
  -i, --info              Zeigt die Versions Information vom my tool CLI
  -c, -l, --l10n <de|en>  Setzt die Sprache / Kultur vom my tool CLI
  --version               Show version information
  -?, -h, --help          Show help and usage information
```

--> My options are translated, but the default ones not.

The both "custom" Options `info` and `language` are added this way

```cs
using L10N = MyTool.L10N.Resource;

...

var infoOption = new Option<bool>(
    new[] { "--info", "-i" },
    L10N.CLI_OPTION_VERSION_INFORMATION
);
rootCommand.AddOption(infoOption);
```

The system options `HelpOption` and `VersionOption` can not modified.

I have installed German, English and French Language Packages via VS 2022 installer.

So how can I change the culture info for the "default" output of the Help text?

- For the titles

  - Description
  - Usage
  - Options
  - ...
- For the options

  - Help
  - Version

Comment: I know, that this is old, but this can help (temporary) somebody.
I have tried the same and did not work, because the version with localization is new one. I have installed 2.0.0-beta4.24112.1 and then the simple:
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
have worked. But in this version there are a lot of changes, like Command is now CliCommand and so on. To get this version you should add the daily builds to your nuget.config, see https://github.com/dotnet/command-line-api

Comment: I only see version `v2.0.0-beta4.22272.1` of beta4

Comment: "Daily builds are available if you add this feed to your nuget.config: https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/dnceng/public/_packaging/dotnet-libraries/nuget/v3/index.json"